# Iterating over symbols (assets) in TradeView (Pine @version=4)

Tags: iterator, iteration, pine-script

I need to iterate over a class of symbols (assets) available in the TradingView system related to BOV. Is it possible to do that?

For comparison: in Mql5 (actual Metatrader scripting language), `SymbolsTotal` and `SymbolName` are functions used for this propose.

With such names, I think I will be able to filter them and work only with assets supposedly interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make individual `security()` calls (max 40) and handle all individual values with separate variable names. There's no way from Pine to iterate through an externally-supplied list.

You could look at the Screener's functionality. If you can do with the generic calcs available there, will be simpler.

Comment: Where did you get such information? I have looked for a reference and manual, but I found only ones closer to tutorials.

Comment: On `security()`:
refman: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_security
usrman: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html
PineCoders on avoiding repainting with the function: https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/
PineCoders FAQ section on MTF: https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#other-timeframes-mtf

Comment: When I asked you for reference, I was wondering how you could know details like "individual security() calls (max 40)". But , in these links, I didn't find any mention of this nature. In which kind of document such information normally is found? (or I have done a mistake?)

Comment: Sry for the misunderstanding:
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/appendix/Pine_compilation_errors.html#script-requesting-too-many-securities
https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-many-plots-security-calls-variables-or-lines-of-code-can-i-use